# How to make parent value optional and child value required in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a project and stuck at a point where the docOne is optional. But if docOne is there, the children of the docOne should be required. Is there any way of achieving this behavior through the schema model? Thank you.

```
const MySchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String },
        docOne: {
            required: false,
            type: {
                docTwo: {
                    required: true,
                    type: {
                        isActive: { type: Boolean, required: true },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true },
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mongoose Mongoose 5.8.0 or above, just add `typePojoToMixed: false` to the scheme options and the validations should work fine.

```
const mySchema = new Schema(
  {
    // ...Schema definition remains the same
  },
  { timestamps: true, typePojoToMixed: false },
);

const myModel = mongoose.model('myModel', mySchema);

const sampleDocument = {
  name: 'John Doe',
};

myModel.validate(sampleDocument); // No Error

sampleDocument.docOne = {};

myModel.validate(sampleDocument); // Throws ValidationError for docOne.docTwo
```

If you are using a lesser version of Mongoose, the other thing that can work is declaring the schema type of the nested objects as a separate schemas:

```
const docTwoSchema = new Schema({
   isActive: { type: Boolean, required: true },
}, 
// Use the "_id: false" option to avoid an autogenerated _id property
{ _id: false }
);

const docOneSchema = new Schema({
  docTwo: {
    type: docTwoSchema,
    required: true,
  }
},
// Use the "_id: false" option to avoid an autogenerated _id property
{ _id: false }
);

const mySchema = new Schema(
  {
      name: { type: String },
      docOne: {
        type: docOneSchema,
        required: false,
      },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

const myModel = mongoose.model('myModel', mySchema);

const sampleDocument = {
  name: 'John Doe',
};

myModel.validate(sampleDocument); // No Error

sampleDocument.docOne = {};

myModel.validate(sampleDocument); // Throws ValidationError for docOne.docTwo
```

Useful Links

- [Mongoose SubDocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

Comment: If I use the second method will it create another _id for the child schema (docTwoSchema)? If so, will it be a problem for querying and etc because it acts as a separate schema?

Comment: Yes, it would create another _id but it won't be a problem for query. However, If you don't want a nested _id, you could specify that in the schema options. I would update the answer with that.

Comment: One more question. What are the benefits of using 'typePojoToMixed' over embedding a schema? What do you think the best solution is?

Comment: Using `typePojoToMixed` would give the same result as embedding a schema(sub-documents) as far as data representation is concerned, and in fact, the resulting schema type for the two are the same. However, because sub-documents are just like every other mongoose document, you have access to document-level features from mongoose, you can add middlewares, custom validation logic, virtual, etc to sub-documents. In contrast, `typePojoToMixed` won't allow you do those. More about sub-documents and the features available [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#what-is-a-subdocument).

Answer (score 1):

try defining the child schema first, and use the child schema in your parent schema.

this way you can make use of sub-documents / embedded-documents where, you can make only **required** to **true**.

you can refer https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html and [https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html#:~:text=Embedded%20documents%20are%20documents%20with,error%20handling%20is%20a%20snap](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html#:%7E:text=Embedded%20documents%20are%20documents%20with,error%20handling%20is%20a%20snap)! for this.